# how to use attribute names like a:b in python spyne?

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, spyne

I am trying to change the attribute names, what I have is

```
class table(ComplexModel):
diffgr=XmlAttribute(String)
rowOrder=XmlAttribute(String)
```

can I change `diffgr` to `diffgr:id`?

as the scheme I am referring to has

```
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
```

I am really stuck, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution ,
in

> diffgr:id

diffgr is a namespace

hence in order to define a sub namepace, Considering my example,
it should be

`id =XmlAttribute(String(sub_ns='diffgr'))`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [rules for giving names in Python](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Beginner_to_Expert/Native_Types):

- Variable names can only include a-z, A-Z, _, and 0-9
- But they may start only wtih a-z, A-Z, _

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is just plain impossible, as it's not valid Python syntax.

Comment: but I have a response like this with such attributes .
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
                     <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                        <CityId>1</CityId>
                        <TheatreId>2</TheatreId>
                        <ScreenId>1</ScreenId>
                        <MovieId>10030</MovieId>
                        <BookingId>957</BookingId>

how do i achieve this? Im getting validation errors.

Comment: @RohitashMathur I don't have the slightest idea of how spynes works so I can't tell you what the proper solution is but it's very certainly documented so check spyne's documentation (FWIW what you're looking for is "xml namespaces"). The only thing I can tell you is that you can NOT have ":" in a Python identifier.